# Xcode 10 build phase sequencing

Tags: xcode, xcode10

What logic does Xcode's modern build system use to sequence or parallelize build phases? I realize that input/output files can be defined to sequence interdependent build phases, but is that the only consideration?

A few of the more complex projects I work on have as many as 10 run-script build phases. While I'd like to benefit from the fact that some can run in parallel, we previously leveraged the legacy build system's respect for top-down sequencing to ensure things happen in order. Are there any simple ways to ensure sequencing that don't rely on input/output files?

Comment: I've watched the WWDC Build System talk - and it doesn't touch on how one might sequence run script phases without reliance on I/O files. It also doesn't mention that run script phases placed after the compilation phase do seem to respect the notion that they should run after compilation implicitly.  Let's say you want to thin a universal framework binary at the end of a build, without modifying the user's workspace. I do this operation in-place in the App bundle. I'm wondering if Input Files for a run script phase can reference files that will be copied into the App Bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, there's no great way.

I wound up doing a couple of things to reduce complexity:

1. Consolidate run-script build phases into two: pre-compile, post-compile
2. Utilize multiprocessing in Python to run groups of scripts in sequence (builds on top of in-house tooling)

I still define "output files" generated during either phase - for instance to ensure that a script-generated (or retrieved) file might be copied into the product bundle. It has reduced overhead, and improved build-times. I still think Apple needs to implement an improved mechanism for sequencing build run-script phases.